# Word VBA uppercase first character of words issues

Tags: vba, ms-word

Ok, lets say i want to uppercase first character in words in selected range in Word document, except some expressions. I have a script which does similar thing, but i have issues with some expressions. In script i use Selection.Range.Case, but the problem is with URL addresses. Id like to leave everything in addresses smallcased, but Selection.Range.Case dissolves URL links to multiple strings, like: https, :, //, /, etc. end every first character of that URL string gets uppercased. The selected range of text is in numbered list, and URLs are last thing before next numbered item. Is there some solution where i can concatenate everything after http:// or https:// into one string right before next numbered item ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide some sample text, an example of exactly *WHAT* is selected, some (minimal) code, the result the code gives and the expected result. Something we can use as a starting point. This is much to vague and general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try something like this if the selected range of text is only in numbered list

```
Sub test()
Dim Pg As Paragraph, Pos As Long, Rng As Range

    For Each Pg In Selection.Paragraphs
        If Not Pg.Range.ListFormat.List Is Nothing Then  'Process only bulleted list
        PgTxt = Pg.Range.Text
        'Debug.Print PgTxt
        Pos = InStr(1, PgTxt, "http")
           If Pos <> 1 Then  'bypass if http found at start of List item then no Case Change
           If Pos > 1 Then Pos = Pos - 1        'http found some where within the List item
           If Pos = 0 Then Pos = Len(PgTxt)     ' if http not found in the list Item
           Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Pg.Range.Start, Pg.Range.Start + Pos)
           Rng.Case = wdTitleWord
           End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, i've incorporated this with my code and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Greedy for accepting & make my score cross 1K. However though I covered two cases 1. URL is within the list Item towards end. 2 No URL in the list item. But I missed 3rd point  i.e. URL  is at the beginning of the list item. Though may not be required specifically in your case,. I am editing the post to incorporate the 3rd case.